# Splitting unspecific length string into columns

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have a column of strings, and I am trying to split them into columns. I've read a couple of stuff online (at the bottom), but I think this is different.

```
stringColumn <- c(
  "50m 26.50 26.50 100m 53.82 27.32",                                     
  NA,                                                                      
  "50m 25.83 25.83 100m 52.99 27.16",                                      
  "25m 12.46 12.46 50m 26.26 13.80 75m 40.02 13.76 100m 53.48 13.46",      
  NA,                                                                      
  "25m 11.72 11.72 50m 25.33 13.61 75m 39.15 13.82 100m 52.55 13.40",      
  "50m 27.20 27.20 100m 56.38 29.18 150m 1:26.39 30.01 200m 1:56.16 29.77")
```

This goes on for a while (970K rows), and the strings follow the same format, either NA or (measurement totaltime timeatcurrentpoint, repeating). Because it is not equal, I can't use regex or str_split. My goal is to get a dataframe with the column names of measurements (25m, 50m, 100m, and so on) with the totaltime at that point.

Desired output:

```
25m     50m     75m     100m    150m  200m    
NA      26.5    NA      53.82   NA    NA       
NA      NA      NA      NA      NA    NA       
12.46   26.26   40.02   53.48   NA    NA       
NA      NA      NA      NA      NA    NA       
11.72   25.33   39.15   52.55   NA    NA       
NA      27.2    NA      56.38   NA    1:56.16
```

Comment: So what's the desired output for this specific sample input?

Comment: Not really. I want the names of the columns to be 25m, 50m, etc, which is always the 1+3x placement in the string, with the time in the column to be the 2+3x placement in the string. Your answer doesn't give that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way using `tidyverse` tools. We can:

1. Use `str_split` with a `(?=\\d+?m)` lookahead to only split each string at the markers between distances (i.e. spaces followed by some digits and `m`);
2. Put into a `tibble`, add a rowid column so we know which measurements came from which strings;
3. `unnest` so each measurement is on its own row;
4. `separate` so each of measurement, totaltime and current time has its own column, and discard current time
5. `spread` to make the measurements the column headers.

Note that this doesn't quite match your sample output, ignoring the column order, but I think it correctly corresponds to the input.

```r
library(tidyverse)

stringColumn = c(
  "50m 26.50 26.50 100m 53.82 27.32",
  NA,
  "50m 25.83 25.83 100m 52.99 27.16",
  "25m 12.46 12.46 50m 26.26 13.80 75m 40.02 13.76 100m 53.48 13.46",
  NA,
  "25m 11.72 11.72 50m 25.33 13.61 75m 39.15 13.82 100m 52.55 13.40",
  "50m 27.20 27.20 100m 56.38 29.18 150m 1:26.39 30.01 200m 1:56.16 29.77"
)

stringColumn %>%
  str_split(" (?=\\d+?m)") %>%
  tibble(strings = .) %>%
  rowid_to_column(var = "stringid") %>%
  unnest(strings) %>%
  separate(strings, c("measurement", "totaltime", "timeatcurrentpoint"), sep = " ") %>%
  select(-timeatcurrentpoint) %>%
  spread(measurement, totaltime)
#> # A tibble: 7 x 8
#>   stringid `100m` `150m`  `200m`  `25m` `50m` `75m` `<NA>`
#>      <int> <chr>  <chr>   <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> 
#> 1        1 53.82  <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  26.50 <NA>  <NA>  
#> 2        2 <NA>   <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  
#> 3        3 52.99  <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  25.83 <NA>  <NA>  
#> 4        4 53.48  <NA>    <NA>    12.46 26.26 40.02 <NA>  
#> 5        5 <NA>   <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  
#> 6        6 52.55  <NA>    <NA>    11.72 25.33 39.15 <NA>  
#> 7        7 56.38  1:26.39 1:56.16 <NA>  27.20 <NA>  <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there anyway to get 25m, 50m, 75m etc in order? I can strip the original string of 'm', but I can't seem to get it as a number. Because I have it until 10,000m (by 25m) this wouldn't be a simple reordering.

Comment: Do you know the full set of values? you can't set integers as column names, unfortunately, so you need to strip the m, convert to integer, order, and then convert back to character and use that to sort the data frame

Answer (score 3):

We can change your data into an expression and evaluate it :

```
stringColumn2 <-  gsub("\\s*(\\d+m)\\s*","'),`\\1`=c('",stringColumn[!is.na(stringColumn)])
stringColumn3 <-  paste0(gsub("^'),","list(",stringColumn2),"'))")
stringColumn4 <-  gsub("\\s+","','",stringColumn3)
stringColumn5 <- paste0("list(",paste(stringColumn4,collapse=","),")")

library(dplyr)
bind_rows(eval(parse(text=stringColumn5)),.id = "id")
# # A tibble: 10 x 7
#    id    `50m` `100m` `25m` `75m` `150m`  `200m` 
#    <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr>  
#  1 1     26.50 53.82  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>    <NA>   
#  2 1     26.50 27.32  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>    <NA>   
#  3 2     25.83 52.99  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>    <NA>   
#  4 2     25.83 27.16  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>    <NA>   
#  5 3     26.26 53.48  12.46 40.02 <NA>    <NA>   
#  6 3     13.80 13.46  12.46 13.76 <NA>    <NA>   
#  7 4     25.33 52.55  11.72 39.15 <NA>    <NA>   
#  8 4     13.61 13.40  11.72 13.82 <NA>    <NA>   
#  9 5     27.20 56.38  <NA>  <NA>  1:26.39 1:56.16
# 10 5     27.20 29.18  <NA>  <NA>  30.01   29.77
```

intermediate steps:

```
stringColumn2[1]
# [1] "'),`50m`=c('26.50 26.50'),`100m`=c('53.82 27.32"
stringColumn3[1]
# [1] "list(`50m`=c('26.50 26.50'),`100m`=c('53.82 27.32'))"
stringColumn4[1]
# [1] "list(`50m`=c('26.50','26.50'),`100m`=c('53.82','27.32'))"
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you. If I wanted only the final time (so 53.82 for the first one and not 27.32 for 100m) how would I do that?

Comment: Is it what you want ? your output in edited answer seems different. I can easily tweak my solution.